# Django templates with "dynamic" determination of the header tag

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to add a help text to a Django app.

To do this, I am going to create a Django template which may be included into another templates.

The trouble is that I do not know what the title tag for my title should be. For example, it can be `<h1>` or `<h2>` or `<h3>`. How to handle the possibility to easily change the tag?

Answer (score 0):

You can create the html in your views, although I wouldn't say it's the best solution you should do.

Try something like this:

**views.py:**

```
def foo(request):
    ...
    html_val = None

    if something:
        html_val = '<h1>something here</h1>'
    elif another_try:
        html_val = '<h2>something else here</h2>'
    else:
        html_val = '<h3>it has to be this one</h3>'

    return response(request, 'template.html', {'html_val': html_val})
```

**template:**

```
{% if html_val %}
    {{ html_val }}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

{{ html_val|safe }}, safe as a filter to ensure that browser doesn't transfor the < as < > as >